# Vue JS two buttons in different components render same component only once

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, emit

Hello To start things of thank you for you time,
I'm new to Vue and I'm stuck with this:
I have a navbar with a link which renders a project component.
Then on the Home component I have a button which should load the same component as the navbar one.
That works BUT only once, if I click on the button on the bottom of the Home section it brings me to the projects and then I cant go back to the home component I have to go on Info and then I can go back to home button the button doesn't bring me anymore to the project page.
[image]

**Main.vue**

```
  <div class="container">
    <navbar @pageWasChanged="currentPage = $event"></navbar>
    <keep-alive>
      <component @pageWasChanged="currentPage = $event" :is="currentPage"></component>
    </keep-alive>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Navbar**

```
<ul class="navigationMenu">
  <li><a @click="pageSelected = 'heropage'">Home</a></li>
  <li><a @click="pageSelected = 'aboutpage'">About</a></li>
  <li><a @click="pageSelected = 'infopage'">Info</a></li>
  <li><a @click="pageSelected = 'gridpage'">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a @click="pageSelected = 'contactpage'">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Button in Home**

```
<div class="btn btnHero" @click="pageSelected = 'gridpage'">See Projects</div>
```

**Import in Navbar and Home**

```
<script>
import pageMixin from "./pageMixin.js";
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {};
  },
  mixins: [pageMixin]
};
</script>
```

**Mixin**

```
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      pageSelected: '',
    }
  },
  watch: {
    pageSelected: function() {
      this.$emit('pageWasChanged', this.pageSelected)
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: I feel like I'm missing the point here a little bit but you're essentially trying to implement routing to different pages by yourself? Any specific reason why you don't use the build-in vue-router (https://router.vuejs.org/installation.html) ? If this isn't what you're trying to achieve I'm sorry. I looked at this 5min straight and it just wouldn't click for me :D

Comment: Thank you so much for you time, yes that is what I was looking for!